# Flask SQLalchemy many-to-many relationship, need secondaryjoin and primaryjoin for some reason

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy docs, http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html  Everything should work fine but I get an error called

Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.rank_r. Specify a 'primaryjoin' expression. If 'secondary' is present, 'secondaryjoin' is needed as well.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'users'
    rank_r = db.relationship('Rank', 
                               secondary=ranks, 
                               backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))


class Rank(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'rank'
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(db.String(STRING_LEN), nullable=False, unique=True)


ranks = db.Table('ranks',    
    db.Column('rank_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('rank.id')),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
)
```

Basically I am trying to do this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, r.name users u INNER JOIN ranks r ON r.id=rr.rank_id INNER JOIN rank rr ON rr.user_id==u.id
```

This would return something like:

```
1 Bob Major
2 Joey Captain
3 Adam Brigadier General
```

This relationship code also seems to fail:

```
rank_r = db.relationship('Rank', 
                           primaryjoin="(rank.c.id==ranks.c.rank_id)",
                           secondary="ranks", 
                           secondaryjoin="(id==ranks.c.user_id)",
                           backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

with error:

StatementError: No column rank.id is configured on mapper Mapper|User|users... (original cause: UnmappedColumnError: No column rank.id is configured on mapper Mapper|User|users...) 'SELECT rank.id AS rank_id, rank.name AS rank_name \nFROM rank, ranks, users \nWHERE ? = ranks.rank_id AND users.id = ranks.user_id' [immutabledict({})]

This is what is displayed when i try to call "User.rank_r" in the template.

Comment: It's not usual for one person to have many ranks-- are you sure you need a many-to-many table, and not just a one-to-many schema?

Comment: I was thinking you are right, a captain cannot be a major. On the other hand, I was thinking about a system that may have more modules/areas, which means in a way, you could be a captain in one module, and major in another module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems alright, I removed a couple of things (just to reduce my imports) and it seems to do what you're after:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'MOO.'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'sqlite://'  # In memory.
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


ranks = db.Table('ranks',
    db.Column('rank_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('rank.id')),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    ranks = db.relationship('Rank',secondary=ranks,
                               backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


class Rank(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'rank'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        bob = User('Bob')
        joey = User('Joey')
        adam = User('Adam')

        major = Rank(name='Major')
        captain = Rank(name='Captain')
        general = Rank(name='General')

        db.session.add_all([bob, joey, adam, major, captain, general])

        bob.ranks.append(major)
        joey.ranks.append(captain)
        adam.ranks.append(general)
        adam.ranks.append(captain)

        db.session.commit()

        users = User.query.all()
        for user in users:
            for rank in user.ranks:
                print '{} {}'.format(user, rank)

                # Bob Major
                # Joey Captain
                # Adam Captain
                # Adam General
```

Comment: Do you mind describing what you did here? It might work in code, but to read this answer is not very good.